# XSLT - Looking for variable elements in for-each loops

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a single XML document that I'm transforming into multiple HTML documents. The problem is that for each document generated I need to look up a different node in a separate collection of XML files.

Imagine my XML looks like this:

```
<index>
  <item>
    <species>Dog</species>
    <tagName>canine</tagName>
  </item>
  <item>
    <species>Cat</species>
    <tagName>feline</tagName>
  </item>
<index>
```

I have a collection of dozens of files that have elements called 'canine'  and 'feline' scattered throughout. I need to call in the right one for each document.

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="index/item">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{species}.html">
      <xsl:for-each select="collection('index.xml')//canine">
        <xsl:value-of select=".">
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm looking for a way to turn that "//canine" into a variable so that in the Dog document it looks for <canine>, in the Cat document it looks for <feline> etc etc.

I can't work out how to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been messing about with variables, but I can't hit on anything that works.

Comment: I don't understand your ultimate goal. One XML file produces multiple HTML files, now you want the HTML files to reference back to XML file? Please show desired result.

Comment: Hi Parfait. The collection of documents has hundreds of different 'species' scattered throughout dozens of different files. The aim is to output a list of all the values for each species to its own seperate species file. Should I add an example to the post to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to turn that "//canine" into a variable so that
>   in the Dog document it looks for `<canine>`, in the Cat document it
>   looks for `<feline>` etc etc.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection('index.xml')//*[name()=current()/tagName]">
```

**Note**:

1. It would be better to use a **key** to select the elements by name - 
   but apparently you cannot do that when your target is a collection
   (?);
2. I am not sure your collection is defined correctly. But that would be a topic for another question.

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning XSLT as I go and I hadn't realised current() could work like this when referencing a collection. This perfectly solved my immediate problem.

I have unfortunately hit a new hurdle as I cannot now work out how to match on this for a template. If I have a follow on question to ask should I post as a separate question? I'm new to stackoverflow. 

Thank you again so much for your help.

Comment: @LiamMcD I am not sure what you mean by  "*match on this for a template*".

Comment: Elsewhere I need to find every paragraph (already wrapped in <p>) that contains the tag in question. Within that paragraph I need to highlight each value of that tag. When I knew the tag name I just used //p[.//canine] to select the paragraphs. Then I applied various templates to it, one of which was a highlighting rule that matched on 'canine'. While your solution is brilliant for my original problem, I can't work out how to match on *[name()=current()/tagName] to apply a template. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way, because a variable defined in one template will not be available to another template (unless you pass it as a parameter). Anyway, I suggest you post a new question, since I am not able to get the exact context from your description - and context is crucial in XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the code that we haven't been shown, you may or maynot be able to use the XSLT `current()` function.

**This code doesn't use** `current()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="index/item">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{species}.html">
      <xsl:sequence select=
      "for $tag in tagName[1] 
         return collection('index.xml')//*[name() eq $tag]/string()"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**In case you want to use the `key()` function** (which *may* speed up the transformation), try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="index/item">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{species}.html">
        <xsl:sequence select=
         "for $t in tagName[1], $doc in collection('index.xml')
           return key('kElemByName', $t, $doc)"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What "*code that we haven't been shown*" would disable the use of the XSLT current() function?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The code could be complicated enough -- for example having nested `<xsl:for-each>` instructions, so that the `current()` is not an `item` element at all.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev thank you! current() did the job for the specific problem in this case, but your solution is elegant and clicked something into place for a different problem I had had. I'm very grateful to you.